# Phaser Tiled tilemap layers not colliding with player

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, tiled

I've been working on a Phaser game for a project at university. All of this is relatively new stuff to me, so I'm learning on the fly. I've managed to create a simple tilemap using Tiled, and got it to import to Phaser sucessfully. However, I can't make the player collide with the 'platform' layer, and I've tried just about everything I can find online.

I've cut down my game code to just what's needed for you to (hopefully) point out my error, but it all runs without errors usually. I can also upload any JSON or Image files that might be needed.

```
var SuddenGame = SuddenGame || {};

var char;
var map;

// GAMEPLAY STATE //
SuddenGame.playState = function() {};

SuddenGame.playState.prototype = {

    init: function() {
        this.game.renderer.renderSession.roundPixels = true;
    },

    create: function() {

        //Setup FPS Counter
        this.game.time.advancedTiming = true;

        //Stop game from pausing if a player tabs out
        this.stage.disableVisibilityChange = true;

        //Import and play background music
        music = this.game.add.audio('menumusic');
        music.play('', 0, 1, true);

        //Create Dotted Background
        this.background = this.game.add.tileSprite(0,
            this.game.height - this.game.cache.getImage('background').height,
            this.game.width,
            this.game.cache.getImage('background').height,
            'background'
        );

        this.dots = this.game.add.tileSprite(0,
            this.game.height - this.game.cache.getImage('dots').height,
            this.game.width,
            this.game.cache.getImage('dots').height,
            'dots'
        );

        //Enable Physics Engine
        this.game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

        //Add level one tilemap 
        map = this.game.add.tilemap('levelone');

        map.addTilesetImage('scifi_platformTiles_32x32', 'scifi_platformTiles_32x32');
        backgroundTiles = map.createLayer('backgroundLayer');
        Objective = map.createLayer('Objective');
        Platform = map.createLayer('Platform');

        this.game.add.existing(Platform);
        this.physics.arcade.enable(Platform);

        map.setCollisionBetween(1, 1000, true, 'Platform');

        Platform.resizeWorld();
        Platform.debug = true;

        this.char = this.add.sprite(50, 470, 'hero');
        this.physics.arcade.enable(this.char);
        this.char.body.gravity.y = 1300;
        this.char.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
        this.char.scale.setTo(2, 2);

        //Create Player Animations
        var idle = this.char.animations.add('idle', [0]);
        var walk = this.char.animations.add('walk', [0, 1, 2, 1]);

        this.game.camera.follow(this.char);

    },

    update: function() {

        this.game.physics.arcade.collide(char, Platform);
        this.physics.arcade.TILE_BIAS = 40;


        if (this.game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT) && !this.char.body.touching.left) {
            this.char.body.velocity.x = -150;
            this.char.animations.play('backwalk', 10, true);
        } else if (this.game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT) && !this.char.body.touching.right) {
            this.char.body.velocity.x = 150;
            this.char.animations.play('walk', 10, true);
        } else if (this.game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.DOWN)) {
            this.char.animations.play('die', 10, true);
        } else {
            this.char.body.velocity.x = 0;
            this.char.animations.play('idle', 7, true);
        }

        if (this.game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR) && this.game.time.now > jumpTimer) {
            {
                this.char.animations.play('jump', 10);
                this.char.body.velocity.y = -1000;
                jumpTimer = this.game.time.now + 750;
            }
        }

        //if (this.cursors.up.isDown && !this.char.body.touching.down ) {
        if (this.game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR) && this.game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.LEFT) && this.char.body.touching.left && this.game.time.now > jumpTimer) {
            this.char.body.velocity.y = -500;
            jumpTimer = this.game.time.now + 1;
        }
        if (this.game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR) && this.game.input.keyboard.isDown(Phaser.Keyboard.RIGHT) && this.char.body.touching.right) {
            this.char.body.velocity.y = -500;
            this.char.body.velocity.x = -2500;
            //jumpTimer = this.game.time.now + 1;
        }

        //More update code here
    },

    render: function() {
        this.game.debug.text(this.game.time.fps || '--', 2, 14, "#00ff00");
    }
}
```

Apologies if I've missed an extremely obvious mistake, I'm pretty sleep deprived right now!